# How can I handle the code purchase.sku when I upgrade Google Play Billing Library 3 to 4?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I use Google Play in-app in my app based the official [sample project](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/main/TrivialDriveKotlin).

The Code A is to handle non-consumable products, it works well when I launch it using `com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:3.0.3` .

After I upgrade the project from Google Play Billing Library 3 to 4, I find the code `purchase.sku` doesn't work, so I have to replace it with `purchase.skus`.

The code of `purchase.skus` can be compiled in `com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:4.0.0`, but I can't get the correct order, the test purchase is refunded after 3 minutes, it seems that Google Play doesn't acknowledge the purchase.

How can I fix the Code A when I upgrade Google Play Billing Library 3 to 4 ?

**Code A**

```
private fun processPurchases(purchasesResult: Set<Purchase>) {
        val validPurchases = HashSet<Purchase>(purchasesResult.size)
        purchasesResult.forEach { purchase ->
            if (purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
                if (purchase.sku.equals(purchaseItem)) {
                //if (purchase.skus.equals(purchaseItem)) {     //sku -> skus  in 4.0
                    if (isSignatureValid(purchase)) {
                        validPurchases.add(purchase)
                    }
                }
            } else if (purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PENDING) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Received a pending purchase of SKU: ${purchase.sku}")
                // handle pending purchases, e.g. confirm with users about the pending
                // purchases, prompt them to complete it, etc.
                mContext.toast(R.string.msgOrderPending)

            } else {
                mContext.toast(R.string.msgOrderError)
            }
        }

        acknowledgeNonConsumablePurchasesAsync(validPurchases.toList())
    }
```

Comment: You probably need to migrate away from v3 because of the playstores update policy, right? If so, I'd suggest to migrate to v5 instead of v4. Because with v4 you will have the migration problem again pretty soon (probably by the end of next year  or so). And some of the methods introduced in v4 are already deprecated in v5 ... It might be bit more work to do, but you spare the effort for the forced migration from v4 to v5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the exact reason of changing this method but I think that's probably because of the new subscriptions model in Google Play. Moreover this new method gets deprecated in the 5.0.0 version.

However, since the `purchase.skus` became a List of Strings, you could just check for your `purchaseItem` inside it. I think it depends on your purchases setup. Assuming your `purchaseItem` is also a `String`, you could either find your `purchaseItem` there:

```
if (purchase.skus.any { it == purchaseItem })
```

or simply take the first one to compare:

```
if (purchase.skus[0] == purchaseItem)
```

Of course, you should debug it to check what's exactly inside the `skus` list and then choose the best way to fix that.